# gantt chart scale

Tags: 2013, gantt-view

Is there a way to change the gantt chart scale? to something other than days

I would like to use it to monitor active contracts but I need a year based not just days (or it gets to big to see)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Gantt chart can be scalled up and down by using the ribbon.

[image: Scall up and down]

You can also use JavaScript to do this and scale down the chart when loading the chart,

Add a Script Editor WebPart or Content Editor WebPart and use code like this

```
<script src="indicate jquery.js location here" type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; ++i) WebPartWPQ2_JSGridController.ZoomOutGantt()
  }, 2000)
})
</script>
```

The script zooms out the Gantt view 3 times from default to achieve the month scale view.

[image: By Month]

Comment: can you explain more about the javascript, Im completely lost on how I would add a content editor webpart that would bring up my list in gantt view

Comment: When you add a new view for a list you can choose for a Gantt View. By default this view shows items by day. After creating the view you can edit the pages of this Gannt view and add a content editor webpart with the JavaScript. By doing the the Gannt view automatically zooms 3 times to show only the months

Comment: Will this script work for SP 2010? I tired this script for SP 2010 and it didn't work for me.